# Regex for excluding several strings

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need a regex that excludes lines with given strings from matching. 
Here`s what I found out so far:

https://regexr.com/42j9r

Regex:

```
(?<!\/)\shttps
```

Test-Text:

```
string.pdf https
string.html https
stringEndingWithSlash/ https
stringEndingWithoutSlash https
```

This only excludes the 3rd line. But I need the expression to match only the lines with strings not ending with .pdf, .html or a slash. So only the last line of the example should match. How can I use the logical | or here? Or is there another solution?
Thank you - all the best,
Sacha

Comment: I can't seem to open your demo.  You might want to include more information directly in your question.

Comment: thanks, I just added the code from regexr.com to my question

Comment: It will be easier to match the lines that violate the rule instead of the lines that adhere to it. And then in whatever programmatic environment you are it should be a piece of cake to deal with the two categories appropriately. Did you try it that way?

Comment: @trincot you`re right but I do a manual replacement in Notepad++ here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
^((?!pdf|html|\/).)*\shttps$
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/cTb0S2/1)

Comment: Keep in mind that using `\s` instead of `[ ]` also allows a tab, newline, etc. character between the extension and the end of line. eg. `"somestring\nhttps"` would match. This is no problem if you know the input is always space separated, but it should at least be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

The following pattern seems to be working:

```
^\w+(?!\.pdf|\.html|\/) https$
```

### Demo

This matches some initial word, which does *not* end in either `.pdf`, `.html`, or a forward slash, which is then followed by a space and `https`.  It uses a negative lookahead to do this.  While there might be solutions that do not use lookarounds, they seem to be easiest way to implement the logic you want.

Answer (score 1):

I realise an answer has been accepted, but it will be more efficient to not do a look ahead at *each individual* character, but do two look-behinds where and when they are needed only:

[`^.*[^\/] https$(?<!\.pdf https)(?<!\.html https)`](https://regex101.com/r/4Tn6wb/3)

... using the `gm` flags.

Comment: good idea, thank you. It works, I use it like this:
\shttps(?<!\.pdf https)(?<!\.html https)(?<!\.jpg https)(?<!\.exe https)(?<!\$ https)(?<!\/ https)

Comment: OK, when the look-behind is about one character (before " https"), it will be more efficient to do a `[^   ]` class for that instead of a look-behind. So: `[^\/$]\shttps$(?<!\.pdf https)(?<!\.html https)(?<!\.jpg https)(?<!\.exe https)`. I would also keep the `$` after `https` so it must occur at the end of a line.